# How to expose json file on dnn

Tags: asp.net, json, dotnetnuke

I have created a dnn module in asp.net which use data stored in locator.json now i need to convert to DNN but it seems as if it DNN cant find the json file. In which folder should i put it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place that file in your module itself. You can access it like this:`url/DesktopModules/ModuleFolderName/locator.json`

To make sure json extension is allowed, you can go to Admin > Site settings and look at the settings for allowed extensions.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Yes I need some help i did go to site settings and added json to allowable extensions, but still it cant find it. what i have discovered is that if i put my data on xml file (location.xml) it works 100%.

Comment: You can restart application from host settings and try again, looks like your settings are not updated

Comment: This error occurs when the file extension of the requested URL is for a MIME type that is not configured on the server. You can add a MIME type for the file extension for files that are not dynamic scripting pages, database, or configuration files. Process those file types using a handler. You should not allows direct downloads of dynamic scripting pages, database or configuration files.

Comment: It is possible that a handler mapping is missing. By default, the static file handler processes all content.</li>  <li>The feature you are trying to use may not be installed.</li>  <li>The appropriate MIME map is not enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not create a MIME map for content that users should not download, such as .ASPX pages or .config files.)</li>  <li>If ASP.NET is not installed.</li> </ul>